# How to extract first three numbers from the runtime input in java?

Tags: java

Im trying to extract the first three numbers from user input.
java methods or calculations. anything is fine.

Comment: Tried mathematical manipulations.. 
http://www.w3resource.com/java-exercises/conditional-statement/java-conditional-statement-exercise-6.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring() method. Eg. if your user input is stored in a variable called `value` you can use

```
String theFirstThreeNumbers = value.substring(0,2);
```

I hope this helps

Comment: What if it needs to be int?

Comment: Then you can use `Integer.parseInt(yourStringValue)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need maths, as you just need the first three digits.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    System.out.println((char) System.in.read());
```

prints the first three characters/digits.